# "Casting" MySQL TIMESTAMP values to a DATETIME column: any gotchas?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have a system where, from time to time, the code will INSERT a new value in a given table. Let's say that table has these 2 columns:

1. ID: int(11)
2. Date: TIMESTAMP

And the "Date" column is defined to have the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value. So, from time to time, the code does a:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (ID) VALUES ('$bla');
```

And we get the new value and the TIMESTAMP when it was inserted.

Now, I want to get that TIMESTAMP value and insert it into another table's DATETIME column (this is a legacy system that I'm hacking, and I can't/rather not touch this other table's definitions).

My question is: can I just take that TIMESTAMP value as-is and insert it in the other table's DATETIME column without any gotchas? From what I've read, the main difference between both types is in timezone handling, but in my case:

- Both tables are in the same database.
- There's only one copy of the DB (it's not like we are replicating DB's from different countries).
- The dates inserted all originate from the same country.

I'm using MySQL 5.5 and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: can I just take that TIMESTAMP value as-is and insert it in the other table's DATETIME column without any gotchas?

Yes.

You've correctly observed that the `DATETIME` values will be recorded with reference to the currently chosen timezone.